# Подскажите, как убрать скролл

Tags: html

Подскажите, как убрать прокрутку на сайте (скролл) полоса сбоку

Answer (score 1):

Впишите css =>

```
html { overflow:  hidden; }
```

Comment: я пробовал, тогда не листает скролл при добавление

Comment: Ну так вы про это и писали. Вы уточните что именно хотите сделать. Чем вам мешает эта полоска и как вы собираетесь отобразить все данные без прокрутки?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.child{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;    
    overflow: auto;
}
.parent{
    width: 85px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
   bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а куда исчез правый борт?

Comment: скролл убран на свою ширину  за правый край div'а

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* хром, сафари */
body::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0; }
 
/* ie 10+ */
body { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
 
/* фф (свойство больше не работает, других способов тоже нет)*/
body { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }

*{font-size:1.3em;}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vulputate dapibus lorem et faucibus. Pellentesque lacus libero, scelerisquem lobortis dolor.
Vivamus non ullamcorper ligula. s et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin tristique lacinia enim at molestie. Donec venenatis orci semper libero lacinia cursus. Curabitur id maximus metus. Pellentesque ut ex auctor, cursus tortor non, porttitor lacus. Curabitur bibendum tincidunt egestas.

Sed volutpat maximus dui, sed ultrices enim bibendum ut. Aliquam euismod convallis diam eu tincidunt. Duis ornare et purus quis dictum. Nulla eu lectus tincidunt, tristique mi quis, blandit orci. Suspendisse cursus magna neque, at semper leo ornare ut. Integer ac cursus nunc. Suspendisse quis diam ut libero laoreet condimentum vitae in nunc.

Maecenas sem ante, venenatis nec sem vitae, ornare auctor sem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean ut risus sapien. Nam rutrum nibh elit, vel euismod ligula tristique pharetra. Sed eget nisl ipsum. Nulla cursus metus ut arcu vestibulum, in commodo magna dignissim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi id nunc malesuada, auctor orci at, scelerisque lacus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi quam tortor, laoreet at tellus sed, fringilla sollicitudin elit. Donec at volutpat urna. Nunc sem nulla, consequat in hendrerit a, lacinia et orci. Curabitur eu porttitor leo. Sed porttitor dui orci, at suscipit ligula dictum faucibus. Pellentesque in dolor libero. Mauris tincidunt pellentesque viverra.

Proin sollicitudin auctor eros, eget elementum eros bibendum non. Integer feugiat sapien sit amet sapien maximus, a facilisis metus viverra. Vivamus eget purus fermentum, interdum tellus a, faucibus ligula. Nam ultricies imperdiet elit id interdum. Curabitur id felis et est euismod posuere. Aliquam consequat lectus enim, sit amet pellentesque justo dictum vitae. Proin in mi pretium, dictum mi et, ultricies massa. Aliquam nec nulla elit. Aliquam placerat lacus metus, ut mollis elit egestas non. Ut tristique mattis nibh a lacinia. Maecenas scelerisque tincidunt venenatis. Sed dictum purus id turpisLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vulputate dapibus lorem et faucibus. Pellentesque lacus libero, scelerisque et aliquet non, tincidunt nec diam. Integer vel nisl at mauris tempor lobortis a non diam. Phasellus tincidunt risus sit amet ante dapibus, vel ultricies lorem porttitor. Donec ex lacus, vestibulum vitae arcu ut, bibendum bibendum diam. Mauris euismod turpis pharetra, pharetra arcu id, rhoncus nisi. Etiam sapien risus, ultricies a nisl sit amet, aliquam lobortis dolor.

Vivamus non ullamcorper ligula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin tristique lacinia enim at molestie. Donec venenatis orci semper libero lacinia cursus. Curabitur id maximus metus. Pellentesque ut ex auctor, cursus tortor non, porttitor lacus. Curabitur bibendum tincidunt egestas.

Sed volutpat maximus dui, sed ultrices enim bibendum ut. Aliquam euismod convallis diam eu tincidunt. Duis ornare et purus quis dictum. Nulla eu lectus tincidunt, tristique mi quis, blandit orci. Suspendisse cursus magna neque, at semper leo ornare ut. Integer ac cursus nunc. Suspendisse quis diam ut libero laoreet condimentum vitae in nunc.

Maecenas sem ante, venenatis nec sem vitae, ornare auctor sem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean ut risus sapien. Nam rutrum nibh elit, vel euismod ligula tristique pharetra. Sed eget nisl ipsum. Nulla cursus metus ut arcu vestibulum, in commodo magna dignissim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi id nunc malesuada, auctor orci at, scelerisque lacus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi quam tortor, laoreet at tellus sed, fringilla sollicitudin elit. Donec at volutpat urna. Nunc sem nulla, consequat in hendrerit a, lacinia et orci. Curabitur eu porttitor leo. Sed porttitor dui orci, at suscipit ligula dictum faucibus. Pellentesque in dolor libero. Mauris tincidunt pellentesque viverra.

Proin sollicitudin auctor eros, eget elementum eros bibendum non. Integer feugiat sapien sit amet sapien maximus, a facilisis metus viverra. Vivamus eget purus fermentum, interdum tellus a, faucibus ligula. Nam ultricies imperdiet elit id interdum. Curabitur id felis et est euismod posuere. Aliquam consequat lectus enim, sit amet pellentesque justo dictum vitae. Proin in mi pretium, dictum mi et, ultricies massa. Aliquam nec nulla elit. Aliquam placerat lacus metus, ut mollis elit egestas non. Ut tristique mattis nibh a lacinia. Maecenas scelerisque tincidunt venenatis. Sed dictum purus id turpisLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vulputate dapibus lorem et faucibus. Pellentesque lacus libero, scelerisque et aliquet non, tincidunt nec diam. Integer vel nisl at mauris tempor lobortis a non diam. Phasellus tincidunt risus sit amet ante dapibus, vel ultricies lorem porttitor. Donec ex lacus, vestibulum vitae arcu ut, bibendum bibendum diam. Mauris euismod turpis pharetra, pharetra arcu id,  lacinia enim at molestie. Donec venenatis orci semper libero lacinia cursus. Curabitur id maximus metus. Pellentesque ut ex auctor, cursus tortor non, porttitor lacus. Curabitur bibendum tincidunt egestas.

Sed volutpat maximus dui, sed ultrices enim bibendum ut. Aliquam euismod convallis diam eu tincidunt. Duis ornare et purus quis dictum. Nulla eu lectus tincidunt, tristique mi quis, blandit orci. Suspendisse cursus magna neque, at semper leo ornare ut. Integer ac cursus nunc. Suspendisse quis diam ut libero laoreet condimentum vitae in nunc.

Maecenas sem ante, venenatis nec sem vitae, ornare auctor sem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean ut risus sapien. Nam rutrum nibh elit, vel euismod ligula tristique pharetra. Sed eget nisl ipsum. Nulla cursus metus ut arcu vestibulum, in commodo magna dignissim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi id nunc malesuada, auctor orci at, scelerisque lacus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi quam tortor, laoreet at tellus sed, fringilla sollicitudin elit. Donec at volutpat urna. Nunc sem nulla, consequat in hendrerit a, lacinia et orci. Curabitur eu porttitor leo. Sed porttitor dui orci, at suscipit ligula dictum faucibus. Pellentesque in dolor libero. Mauris tincidunt pellentesque viverra.

Proin sollicitudin auctor eros, eget elementum eros bibendum non. Integer feugiat sapien sit amet sapien maximus, a facilisis metus viverra. Vivamus eget purus fermentum, interdum tellus a, faucibus ligula. Nam ultricies imperdiet elit id interdum. Curabitur id felis et est euismod posuere. Aliquam consequat lectus enim, sit amet pellentesque justo dictum vitae. Proin in mi pretium, dictum mi et, ultricies massa. Aliquam nec nulla elit. Aliquam placerat lacus metus, ut mollis elit egestas non. Ut tristique mattis nibh a lacinia. Maecenas scelerisque tincidunt venenatis. Sed dictum purus id turpisLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vulputate dapibus lorem et faucibus. at tellus sed, fringilla sollicitudin elit.  </p>
```